# HTML styles in quoted emails

Tags: html, css, email, sendgrid

I'm sending mail reports (using sendgrid) and I have a problem with styling. The received emails are displayed correctly in Gmail client, but when I try to forward o reply this emails the styles turns broken.

The received emails looks like this (fine):
[image]

When I try to forward, the styles of quoted emails shows broken:
[image]

How can I manage styles in html to avoid this problem?

Thanks in advance!
Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of linking a stylesheet like normal HTML on the web, you must inline your CSS styles so they are part of the HTML markup. Every element needs to have its relevant styles inside a `style` attribute, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center">
      <h1 style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 24px; line-height: 1.3; font-weight: bold; color: blue;">
        Your email title
      </h1>
      <p style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 16px; line-height: 1.5; color: #333333;">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Etiam finibus varius ligula, eget dignissim dui ultrices vel. Nunc blandit turpis et sapien tincidunt, sed placerat ipsum convallis. Duis vel aliquet mi. In a ullamcorper nunc, in lobortis libero. Phasellus accumsan consectetur felis nec sodales.
      </p>
      <a style="font-family: Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 18px; font-weight: bold; line-height: 40px; height: 40px; color: red; height: 40px; background: white; border: 2px solid red; text-decoration: none;">
        A link button
      </a>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hopefully this helps you.